# Photoswipe gallery nav buttons not working when online

Tags: html, button, syntax-error, nav, photoswipe

When I was building my site everything was working correctly, but since my site went online the nav button wasn't working anymore. (Actually, in my phone I’ve found some random emoticon instead of the buttons) I don’t understand why when it wasn't online everything was working and now it’s not anymore. The site is at [www.smartgenius.it](http://www.smartgenius.it). Can you have a look and see if you notice something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've just checked out your site and all the nav tags are working perfectly on both my desktop as well as my phone. You can try clearing the cache on your phone and looking at it again or view it through incognito mode.
Sometimes when I look at my site during construction and then again when it's done, it looks a little odd.